# How to write shift_elements function in C?

Tags: c, insertion-sort

I have this question in C language:

> Implement the function: **shift_element(int * arr, int i)**.

The function will get a pointer (not necessarily the beginning of the array) and the function will move the `i` next values to the right. Note that the function assumes that there is memory for at least i+1 cells after the pointer of the array.

Isn't it a swap function that I can use in Insertion sort? I don't understand the question properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcpy`:

```
void shift_element(int * arr, int i)
{
    // moves i bytes from arr to arr + 1
    memcpy(arr + 1, arr, i);
}
```

Description from the manual:

```
The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory
area dest.  The memory areas must not overlap.  Use memmove(3) if the
memory areas do overlap.
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without a built-in function?

Comment: While it totally would be the right approach in a professional context, I doubt this could be the purpose of the present exercise. I think the goal is precisely to think about the way we could properly implement this by ourselves…

Comment: Yes, your answer definitely seems to fit the question better.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to **shift** your elements, you don't actually need to sort them, nor even to swap a couple of them neither. As you said, you just need to move each element to the next place.

A regular loop should be enough, in which you'll simply do `arr[index+1] = arr[index]` but be careful to walk **from right to left** (having a loop starting from `i` and descending to 0), or you will clobber the elements you're about to move.

Please note that in most programming languages, a "shift" function generally does the opposite : shifting all elements to the left, returning the one at top of the list, then discarding it.